# How to extract 8 integers from a 256 vector using intel intrinsics?

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm trying to enhance the performance of my code by using the 256bit vector (Intel intrinsics - AVX).

I have an I7 Gen.4 (Haswell architecture) processor supporting SSE1 to SSE4.2 and AVX/AVX2 Extensions.

This is the code snippet that I'm trying to enhance:

```
/* code snipet */
kfac1 = kfac  + factor;  /* 7 cycles for 7 additions */
kfac2 = kfac1 + factor;
kfac3 = kfac2 + factor;
kfac4 = kfac3 + factor;
kfac5 = kfac4 + factor;
kfac6 = kfac5 + factor;
kfac7 = kfac6 + factor;

k1fac1 = k1fac  + factor1;  /* 7 cycles for 7 additions */
k1fac2 = k1fac1 + factor1;
k1fac3 = k1fac2 + factor1;
k1fac4 = k1fac3 + factor1;
k1fac5 = k1fac4 + factor1;
k1fac6 = k1fac5 + factor1;
k1fac7 = k1fac6 + factor1;

k2fac1 = k2fac  + factor2;  /* 7 cycles for 7 additions */
k2fac2 = k2fac1 + factor2;
k2fac3 = k2fac2 + factor2;
k2fac4 = k2fac3 + factor2;
k2fac5 = k2fac4 + factor2;
k2fac6 = k2fac5 + factor2;
k2fac7 = k2fac6 + factor2;
/* code snipet */
```

From the Intel Manuals, I found this.

- an integer addition ADD takes 1 cycle (latency).
- a vector of 8 integers (32 bit) takes 1 cycle also.

So I've tried ton make it this way:

```
fac  = _mm256_set1_epi32 (factor )
fac1 = _mm256_set1_epi32 (factor1)
fac2 = _mm256_set1_epi32 (factor2)

v1   = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,kfac6,kfac5,kfac4,kfac3,kfac2,kfac1,kfac)
v2   = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,k1fac6,k1fac5,k1fac4,k1fac3,k1fac2,k1fac1,k1fac)
v3   = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,k2fac6,k2fac5,k2fac4,k2fac3,k2fac2,k2fac1,k2fac)

res1 = _mm256_add_epi32 (v1,fac) ////////////////////
res2 = _mm256_add_epi32 (v2,fa1) // just 3 cycles  //
res3 = _mm256_add_epi32 (v3,fa2) ////////////////////
```

But the problem is that these factors are going to be used as tables indexes ( table[kfac] ... ). So i have to extract the factor as seperate integers again.
I wonder if there is any possible way to do it??

Comment: Latency isn't a big deal when you have that many independent adds happening.  The throughput of 4 scalar `add` instructions per clock is much more relevant.  If `k1fac2` and so on are already in contiguous memory, then using SIMD is possibly worth it.  Otherwise all the shuffling and data transfer to get them in/out of vector regs is makes it definitely not worth it.  (And AVX2 gather is slow on Haswell, otherwise you could use that for the table loads.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A smart compiler could get `table+factor` into a register and use indexed addressing modes to get `table+factor+k1fac6` as an address.  Check the asm, and if the compiler doesn't do this for you, try changing the source to hand-hold the compiler:

```
const int *tf = table + factor;
const int *tf2 = table + factor2;   // could be lea rdx, [rax+rcx*4]  or something.

...

foo = tf[kfac2];
bar = tf2[k2fac6];     // could be  mov r12, [rdx + rdi*4]
```

---

But to answer the question you asked:

Latency isn't a big deal when you have that many independent adds happening.  The throughput of 4 scalar `add` instructions per clock on Haswell is much more relevant.

If `k1fac2` and so on are already in contiguous memory, then using SIMD is possibly worth it.  Otherwise all the shuffling and data transfer to get them in/out of vector regs makes it definitely not worth it.  (i.e. the stuff compiler emits to implement `_mm256_set_epi32 (0,kfac6,kfac5,kfac4,kfac3,kfac2,kfac1,kfac)`.

You could avoid needing to get the indices back into integer registers by using an AVX2 gather for the table loads.  But gather is slow on Haswell, so probably not worth it.  Maybe worth it on Broadwell.

On Skylake, gather is fast so it could be good if you can SIMD whatever you do with the LUT results.  If you need to extract all the gather results back to separate integer registers, it's probably not worth it.

---

**If you did need to extract 8x 32-bit integers from a `__m256i` into integer registers**, you have three main choices of strategy:

- Vector store to a tmp array and scalar loads
- ALU shuffle instructions like `pextrd` (`_mm_extract_epi32`).  Use `_mm256_extracti128_si256` to get the high lane into a separate `__m128i`.
- A mix of both strategies (e.g. store the high 128 to memory while using ALU stuff on the low half).

Depending on the surrounding code, any of these three could be optimal on Haswell.

`pextrd r32, xmm, imm8` is 2 uops on Haswell, with one of them needing the shuffle unit on port5.  That's a lot of shuffle uops, so a pure ALU strategy is only going to be good if your code is bottlenecked on L1d cache throughput.  (Not the same thing as memory bandwidth).  `movd r32, xmm` is only 1 uop, and compilers do know to use that when compiling `_mm_extract_epi32(vec, 0)`, but you can also write `int foo = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(vec)` to make it explicit and remind yourself that the bottom element can be accessed more efficiently.

Store/reload has good throughput.  Intel SnB-family CPUs including Haswell can run two loads per clock, and IIRC store-forwarding works from an aligned 32-byte store to any 4-byte element of it.  But make sure it's an aligned store, e.g. into `_Alignas(32) int tmp[8]`, or into a union between an `__m256i` and an `int` array.  You could still store into the `int` array instead of the `__m256i` member to avoid union type-punning while still having the array aligned, but it's easiest to just use C++11 `alignas` or C11 `_Alignas`.

```
 _Alignas(32) int tmp[8];
 _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)tmp, vec);
 ...
 foo2 = tmp[2];
```

However, the problem with store/reload is latency.  Even the first result won't be ready for 6 cycles after the store-data is ready.

A mixed strategy gives you the best of both worlds: ALU to extract the first 2 or 3 elements lets execution get started on whatever code uses them, hiding the store-forwarding latency of the store/reload.

```
 _Alignas(32) int tmp[8];
 _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)tmp, vec);

 __m128i lo = _mm256_castsi256_si128(vec);  // This is free, no instructions
 int foo0 = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(lo);
 int foo1 = _mm_extract_epi32(lo, 1);

 foo2 = tmp[2];
 // rest of foo3..foo7 also loaded from tmp[]

 // Then use foo0..foo7
```

You might find that it's optimal to do the first 4 elements with `pextrd`, in which case you only need to store/reload the upper lane.  Use `vextracti128 [mem], ymm, 1`:

```
_Alignas(16) int tmp[4];
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)tmp,  _mm256_extracti128_si256(vec, 1));

// movd / pextrd for foo0..foo3

int foo4 = tmp[0];
...
```

---

With fewer larger elements (e.g. 64-bit integers), a pure ALU strategy is more attractive.  6-cycle vector-store / integer-reload latency is longer than it would take to get all of the results with ALU ops, but store/reload could still be good if there's a lot of instruction-level parallelism and you bottleneck on ALU throughput instead of latency.

With more smaller elements (8 or 16-bit), store/reload is definitely attractive.  Extracting the first 2 to 4 elements with ALU instructions is still good.  And maybe even `vmovd r32, xmm` and then picking that apart with integer shift/mask instructions is good.

---

Your cycle-counting for the vector version is also bogus.  The three `_mm256_add_epi32` operations are independent, and Haswell can run two `vpaddd` instructions in parallel.  (Skylake can run all three in a single cycle, each with 1 cycle latency.)

Superscalar pipelined out-of-order execution means there's a big difference between latency and throughput, and keeping track of dependency chains matters a lot.  See http://agner.org/optimize/, and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more optimization guides.

Comment: Very good and instructive answer ... I will try to do what you said and see the results.

Comment: @A.nechi: I added a section that answers the actual question, in case people get here from looking at the question title, or from searching.  In your case, I don't think it's going to be worth it just for calculating indices.